# How can i set a static Y Axis for multiple graphs in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem with my Python code. I wrote some test results from a physics project into a csv file. I then wrote a Python script that uses matplotlib to showcase the results in a graph. Basically, I have 10 different series (e.g. position, velocity, acceleration, and seconds), and I want them to be in one figure.

But here is the problem: it completely juggles my Y-axis values and I don't know why. I just want a static Y axis from `-1` to `1` and then to just fill in the different values. The X axis is fine; those are my ticks in seconds.

[image]

I tried some things with `plt.axis` and `plt.axes`, but I am really really stuck here. Here is the code snippet I am talking about:

```
import csv
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as tick


positionM1 = []
positionM2 = []
velocityM1 = []
velocityM2 = []
accel1 = []
accel2 = []
sec = []
forceM1 = []
forceM2 = []
federPressed = []


with open("filename", 'r') as csvfile:
    plots= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        sec.append((row[0]))
        velocityM1.append((row[1]))
        velocityM2.append((row[2]))
        positionM1.append((row[3]))
        positionM2.append((row[4]))
        accel1.append((row[5]))
        accel2.append((row[6]))
        forceM1.append((row[7]))
        forceM2.append((row[8]))
        federPressed.append((row[9]))



plt.axis('normal')
plt.plot(sec, velocityM1, 'b', sec, velocityM2, 'g', sec, positionM1, 'r')
plt.plot(sec, velocityM2, label="VelocityM2")
plt.plot(sec, positionM1, label="PositionM1")
plt.plot(sec, positionM2, label="PositionM2")
plt.plot(sec, accel1, label="AccelerationM1")
plt.plot(sec, accel2, label="AccelerationM2")
plt.plot(sec, forceM1, label="Newton M1")
plt.plot(sec, forceM2, label="Newton M1")
plt.plot(sec, federPressed, label="Feder gepresst")
plt.legend(fontsize=10)
plt.grid('True')


plt.show()
```

And here is the CSV file:

```
0.0000,0.5000,0.0000,0.0000,0.3000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,
0.0250,0.5000,0.0000,0.0125,0.3000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,
0.0500,0.5000,0.0000,0.0250,0.3000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,
0.0750,0.5000,0.0000,0.0375,0.3000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,
0.1000,0.5000,0.0000,0.0500,0.3000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,
0.1250,0.5000,0.0000,0.0625,0.3000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,
0.1500,0.5000,0.0000,0.0750,0.3000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,
0.1750,0.5000,0.0000,0.0875,0.3000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,
0.2000,0.5000,0.0000,0.1000,0.3000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,
0.2250,0.5000,0.0000,0.1125,0.3000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,
0.2500,0.5000,0.0000,0.1250,0.3000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,
0.2750,0.5000,0.0000,0.1375,0.3000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,
0.3000,0.5000,0.0000,0.1500,0.3000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,
0.3250,0.5000,0.0000,0.1625,0.3000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,
0.3500,0.5000,0.0000,0.1750,0.3000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,
0.3750,0.5000,0.0000,0.1875,0.3000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,
0.4000,0.5000,0.0000,0.2000,0.3000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,
0.4250,0.4500,0.0500,0.2113,0.3012,-2.0000,2.0000,-1.0000,1.0000,0.1000,
0.4500,0.4050,0.0950,0.2214,0.3036,-1.8000,1.8000,-0.9000,0.9000,0.0900,
0.4750,0.3639,0.1361,0.2305,0.3070,-1.6450,1.6450,-0.8225,0.8225,0.0822,
0.5000,0.3256,0.1744,0.2386,0.3114,-1.5311,1.5311,-0.7656,0.7656,0.0766,
0.5250,0.2892,0.2108,0.2458,0.3167,-1.4555,1.4555,-0.7278,0.7278,0.0728,
0.5500,0.2538,0.2462,0.2522,0.3228,-1.4163,1.4163,-0.7082,0.7082,0.0708,
0.5750,0.2185,0.2815,0.2576,0.3299,-1.4125,1.4125,-0.7063,0.7063,0.0706,
0.6000,0.1824,0.3176,0.2622,0.3378,-1.4440,1.4440,-0.7220,0.7220,0.0722,
0.6250,0.1446,0.3554,0.2658,0.3467,-1.5116,1.5116,-0.7558,0.7558,0.0756,
0.6500,0.1042,0.3958,0.2684,0.3566,-1.6170,1.6170,-0.8085,0.8085,0.0809,
0.6750,0.0601,0.4399,0.2699,0.3676,-1.7629,1.7629,-0.8814,0.8814,0.0881,
0.7000,0.0113,0.4887,0.2702,0.3798,-1.9528,1.9528,-0.9764,0.9764,0.0976,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@mrzo and @user3053452 are good: they make use of libraries which simplifies the job, so you are less prone to make errors.

But let me explain why your code does not work, I think is important to understand that.

You forgot to convert the numbers to float. You currently have strings. If you do:

```
with open("data.txt", 'r') as csvfile:
    plots= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    rows = [list(map(float, line[:-1])) for line in plots]
    for row in rows:
        sec.append((row[0]))
        velocityM1.append((row[1]))
        #and so on for all the stuffs to be plotted, as in your code
```

You can get what you want.

Let me explain what I do in this line: `rows = [list(map(float, line[:-1])) for line in plots]`. The list comprehension convert the element each line from the csv in a float using the [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) built-in function. I need to remove the last element by slicing over line and take all elemens but the last one (the `[:-1]` stuff) because is empty, due to the trailing comma in you csv file.

This way x and y coordinates are correctly interpreted by matplotlib and placed where they are meant to be.

Comment: Thank you very much, it does work now. As i said, i was pretty sure i just did a simple mistake, completly forgot about casting it into floats...

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the pandas module especially its DataFrame class and read_csv function. I think it will make a lot of things easier for you (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

A possible solution with pandas:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# names of the columns in the csv file
variables = [
    "time", "velocityM1", "velocityM2", "PositionM1", "PositionM2", 
    "AccelerationM1", "AccelerationM2", "Newton M1", "Newton M2",
    "Feder gepresst"
]

# Load the csv file, set the first column automatically as index (time column). 
# There is no header line in the file, therefore we have to set it to None
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, index_col=0, names=variables)

# plot all columns and show the plot
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

Please note that I removed the trailing commas from each line in your csv file to let this work.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

A solution using numpy:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',')
my_data = np.delete(my_data, -1, axis=1)
names = ['positionM1','positionM2','velocityM1','velocityM2','accel1','accel2',
         'sec','forceM1','forceM2','federPressed']

plt.axis('normal')
for i, name in zip(range(1, my_data.shape[1]), names):
    plt.plot(my_data[:,0], my_data[:,i], label=name)
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The solution here is to load your data to numpy array from csv using `genfromtext` and then plotting them column by column. Given that 1st column is time, I started for loop with 2nd column, hence `range(1, ...)`

Since your data has `,` at the end I used `my_data = np.delete(my_data, -1, axis=1)` to remove last column.

**Output:**

[image]